# How to fit area under curve through clipping in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I have a simple arbitrary curve and a straight line below the curve. The curve represents just some arbitrary function. But my point is how do I precisely fit an area between two paths, given I have two arbitrary points on the curve which is projected on the straight line under the curve. I tried clipping it but what it does is clip below the curve and not above. The shaded area does not fit with the curve which can be seen well when zoomed in.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw (-2,2) .. controls (0,1) and (3,1) .. coordinate[pos=0.8](A) coordinate[pos=0.925](B) (5,2);
    \draw (A) --++ (0,-43.25pt) coordinate(C);
    \draw (B) --++ (0,-51.15pt) coordinate(D);
    \filldraw[violet] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clip the violet area, you first need to define the area to clip. The following could be a way to achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (-2,2) .. controls (0,1) and (3,1) .. coordinate[pos=0.8](A) coordinate[pos=0.925](B) (5,2) -- (5,0) -- (-2,0) -- cycle;
        \coordinate (C) at (A |- 0,0);
        \coordinate (D) at (B |- 0,0);
        \draw[fill=violet] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw (-2,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw (-2,2) .. controls (0,1) and (3,1) .. (5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

`(A |- 0,0)` here means: Get the x-value of `A` and the y-value of `0,0`, which would be the coordinate on the straight line directly under coordinate `A`.

You could store the path of the curve in some macro if you don't want to repeatedly type it, such as in:

```
\newcommand{\mycurve}{ (-2,2) .. controls (0,1) and (3,1) .. (5,2) }

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \mycurve coordinate[pos=0.8](A) coordinate[pos=0.925](B) -- (5,0) -- (-2,0) -- cycle;
        \coordinate (C) at (A |- 0,0);
        \coordinate (D) at (B |- 0,0);
        \draw[fill=violet] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw (-2,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw \mycurve;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I any case, the result would be:

[image]